# date -d not working on mac

Tags: linux, macos, date

I am trying to convert a timestamp to a number of seconds and it is not working as intended on a mac. On linux I can run:

`date -d "2015-06-11 12:39" +%s` and I get `1434044340` as intended. However, when I run that same command on a mac, I get

```
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

what is the corresponding mac command and/or how can I get the original command to work on a mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try it this way `date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "2015-06-11 12:39" +%s`. I've just tried it myself.

The commands for date are a bit different on macs than on a Linux based operating system.

Comment: While the idea is sound, for posterity, it should be `date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "2015-06-11 12:39" +%s` since the input format is predefined.

Comment: Point taken, I'll change it. It was just the format i use the most often :P

Comment: Yes, I am using this now and it is working as requested - thanks! (You are supposed to wait a bit before marking a solution as correct, so I was giving it a minute)

Comment: Haha, i just wanted to know in case i needed to do some digging ;) glad i could help!

Comment: How do I add +1 day the above command so it prints 2015-06-12

Answer (score 15):

3 years later :)
Try this:
    `brew install coreutils ; echo "alias date=gdate" >> ~/.bash_profile`
Then run your command

Comment: It would be nice to know why `gdate` and not `date -d`.